# Bootstrap responsive navbar collapse misalignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created a navigation bar with a simple contact button on the right hand side using twitter bootstrap v3.

However when the screen size is < 768px it drops outside of the navigation bar.

This is the section with the problem.

```
<div class="pull-right">      
    <ul class="nav">
     <a href="#"><li id="myContactButton" class="nav-text alternate">Contact Us</li></a>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x9NBC/

I've had a look through the @media queries in the css but I can't figure out which is making it drop down like that.

How can I make it stay in line with the navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these Sections

I have  added `pull-left` class to some of the element, mentioning below

```
 <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
```

Pull left for button

```
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```

Add pull-left for anchor tag also

```
<a href="index.php" class="pull-left">
```

Here is the Demo http://jsfiddle.net/x9NBC/6/